# WARNING:tensorflow:Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to the jupyter notebook. I'm following a tutorial in which model have been saved and then used in making new model, but it showing me an error of `input_shape` in the 1st layer. I have added `input_shape` in input layer(1st layer) but still it showing me the same error. How to resolve it?

I have also tried by changing the extension of the file as .h5 but still have warning error

```
[1]
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(4,4,512)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

[2]
model.save('epic_num_reader.model')

[3]
new_model= tf.keras.models.load_model('epic_num_reader.model')
```

This new_model code generates warning error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Sequential models without an `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer state. As a result, your model isstarting with a freshly initialized optimizer.
```

Comment: As the warning suggests, your first layer need the argument input_shape

Answer (score 0):

resolved :)

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1).reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1).reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())   
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

Comment: You can also try using the functional form which has `InputLayer` as the first layer